# SIM card used with smart card user certificate

Tags: certificates, windows, smartcard

Is it possible to put a smart card user certificate (Windows) on a SIM card? (SIM card already has telecom info on it).

I'm using Win 2012 and have tried, but I am getting this error "smart card cannot perform the requested operation..."

If not, what smart card do I need to have to install a smart card user certificate? I will use smart card to log in to Windows VPN.

Comment: Because this is about pairing a SIM card with Win 2012, I would move this to ServerFault, but this question might get closed pretty quickly there because it is confusing. Did the error you get happen because you tried to use a SIM, or was it with the smart card? You will also have to explain a lot more about how you are trying to configure Windows and the smart card.

Comment: What documentation have you read to get smart card authentication to work?

Comment: shroeder : this : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739449%28v=WS.10%29.aspx and this : http://henrysluiman.blogspot.de/2011/12/installing-windows-2008-r2-certificate.html

Comment: ok - but you haven't answered the other question I had. You need to walk us through the steps you took.

Answer (score 1):

The SIM Card is not able to fulfill the requests sent to it when trying to place a certificate on it. The required commands are not available. Most (nearly all) SIM-Cards are not able to be extended in functionality either.

Answer (score 0):

SIM cards are smartcards, but that doesn't mean that they can be used for any and all PKI purposes. Smartcards have applets and/or the integrated circuit (IC) is designed for a particular purpose. Depending on the applet and/or the IC design, different smartcards have different uses and capabilities.

SIM cards are designed to work woth smartphones and not to be used for PKI. Nevertheless, there are some solutions in some countries that allow the SIM card to also have a PKI certificate for digital signatures. These solutions and scheme specific. For example, Estonia has SmartID. These SIM cards cannot be used as regular PKI smartcards, though. They cannot be used with a regular card reader on a computer. Those SIM cards respond to signals receiver from the network provider and display a notification on the smartphone to confirm transactions.